# Convert certificate to byte array

Tags: c, ssl-certificate

How to convert a certificate(PEM/DER format) into byte array?

I don't have file system on my device and want to use the client certificate on it. So I want to copy this SSL certificate into a buffer(unsigned char). I have certificate file on my windows machine.

What is the right way to convert the certificate into array? Simple character copy will work?

Vishal N

Comment: Which library and compiler+linker do you use?

Answer (score 2):

check this code, explanations are added as comments ,

> 1 Load the file into BIO structure
>
> 2 Convert it to x509 using PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX
>
> 3 convert the x509 to unsigned char * using i2d_X509

```
int main()
{    
    X509 *x509;    
    BIO *certBio = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());   
    char * path = "E:\\share\\TempCert.pem"; /* directory path where certificate exists*/
    int len;
    unsigned char *buf;   

    buf = NULL;
    BIO_read_filename(certBio, path);
    x509 = PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(certBio, NULL, 0, NULL);      /*loading the certificate to x509 structure*/
    len = i2d_X509(x509, &buf);     /*loading the certificate to unsigned char buffer*/

    /* You can use this buf as BYTE array since BYTE is typedef of unsigned char and len will contain the length(size) of the certificate */
    BIO_free_all(certBio);  
    return 0;
}
```

check the [i2d_X509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/i2d_X509.html), [PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/crypto/PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX.html) functions for more details.

This buffer can be used to create `PCCERT_CONTEXT` structure.

Comment: I have the opposite problem: how can I convert byte array to certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use gcc+gnu-binutils+openssl, you can use [ld](http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/ld-blobs-2007-07-13-15-50) to include a file literal into the program. Then you use [d2i_X509](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html) to parse the literal into a X509 structure.

First run `ld -r -b binary -o cert.crt.o cert.crt` (cert.crt MUST be in DER form, I don't know if .crt is the correct extension for DER).

example.c

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned char _binary_cert_crt_start[];
extern unsigned char _binary_cert_crt_end[];

int main()
{
   X509 *cert;
   const unsigned char *buf = _binary_cert_crt_start;
   unsigned const char** inp = &buf;
   cert = d2i_X509(NULL, inp, _binary_cert_crt_end-_binary_cert_crt_start);
   printf("%p\n", cert);
   return !cert;
}
```

Then you compile this program with `gcc -o ct example.c cert.crt.o -lcrypto`.