# Open SSL extract certificate from X509 structure into char array

Tags: c, certificate, openssl, x509

I am using OpenSSL to construct my own self signed certificate which I have in an X509 structure. I wan't to extract the certificate data out of the X509 structure into a char array.

I am aware of the following macro:

```
PEM_Write_X509(file *, certificate *)
```

This will output to a file something like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE------
DATAHERE
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What I really want is just the "DATAHERE" part directly into a char array. There are a baffling number of macros for doing various things, but I haven't stumbled across one that does what I'm after. Is there anything suitable that I haven't found?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836467/convert-certificate-to-byte-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BEGIN and END sections are boundaries for the PEM text. This is standard convention. I believe, removing these sections will make the certificate unusable.

Comment: You won't find any API giving you only there DATAHERE part because the PEM certificate consists of all the three sections.

Answer (score 0):

What you presented is a PEM-encoded representation of the certificate (which by itself is a DER data).

In your case you just strip this text and you have base64-encoded DER data of the certificate.